# Find value of x such that x! less than or equal to 1000

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the maximum value of $x$ such that $x! \leq 1000$. I tried the following:

```
NSolve[Factorial[x] - 1000 == 0, x]
```

but I got this message:

> During evaluation of In[67]:= NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> Out[67]= {{x -> -2.001}}

What is the correct function to use here?

Comment: Factorial grows fast enough to do this by hand... the answer is 6! = 720.

Comment: @zeldredge, Yes but I other have much larger numbers to go through so I want a programmatic solution.

Comment: You can easily do it procedurally using `While`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Maximize` with a constraint:

```
Maximize[{x!, x! <= 1000}, x, Integers]
```

> {720, {x -> 6}}

Or `ArgMax` for the value of `x` alone:

```
ArgMax[{x!, x! <= 1000}, x, Integers]
```

> 6

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with: `Maximize[{Log2[x], Log2[x] <= 1000}, x, Integers]`

Comment: @I.K. Actually, it does work. It provides a symbolic result. It's providing you an exact integer assignment for `x` (or at least it does for me on v10.1). If you want a numerical approximation of the resulting for the maximized *value*, you should use `FullSimplify` (for value of `1000`) or `N`, or similar.

Comment: @I.K. So, for simplification, see `Maximize[{Log2[x], Log2[x] <= 1000}, x, Integers] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: So I used this syntax to express the answer more manageably : `N[Maximize[{Log2[x], Log2[x] <= 1000}, x, Integers], 5]`. Is that the idiomatic way to do that in Mathematica. Also can you tell me why the output $\{1000.0, \{x -> 1.0715*10^301\}\}$ has 1000.0 in it?

Comment: @I.K. `Log2` is a bit special case because `x` is 2^1000 and `Log2` of it is precisely 1000. In this case value of maximization is also known, but since simplification in general is non-trivial, not much simplification is done by default. To force more (in this case enough) `FullSimplify` produces precise answer. Your expression with `N[..., 5]` requests precisely five digits of precision; so that's what (`1000.0`)  you get.

Comment: @I.K. If you are unaware of several types of numbers Mathematica sees as different kinds of entities, I suggest reading `tutorial/NumbersOverview` in the documentation.

Comment: @I.K. Correcting my first comment above: "If you want a numerical approximation of the resulting for the maximized value, you should use `FullSimplify` (for value of 1000) or `N`, or similar." should have been "If you want a simplified precise maximized value, you should use `FullSimplify` (for value of 1000) or `N` for an approximate value (expressed as `1000.` in Mathematica."

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 1;
While[n! < 1000, Null; n++];
n - 1
```

(* 6 *)

**Speedups for large n**

If you seek the solutions to very large $n$ problems, it is faster if you use Stirling's approximation, that is:

$n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left({ n \over e} \right)^n$.

Start at a safe lower limit (e.g., Log[Target]), then iteratively search through increasing $n$ (which is much faster and lower space complexity than calculating factorials).  Once you get an estimate of $n$ based on the Stirling approximation, re-start a true factorial search starting at a safe lower limit, say $1/10$ the approximation result.

There are cleverer methods based on number theory, but I sense you don't need such sophistication here.

The `Maximize[{x!, x! <= Target}, x, Integers]` from @Kirma works quite well to large `Target`.

Comment: One can also use relation of `Factorial` and `Gamma` functions for something like: `Floor[InverseFunction[Gamma][10^100] - 1] (* 69 *)`

Comment: @kirma  Ah... that solution is the best, `InverseFunction`---*Mathematica* style.  +1

Comment: Also, you can do things like `Floor[InverseFunction[LogGamma][Log[10] (10^7)] - 1] (* 1723507 *)` for numbers up to at least 10^(10^7), like in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the <= factorial result result pretty quickly:

```
invfactorialbound[n_] :=
 Module[{bound = Ceiling[1 + Log[0.3989 (0.03653 + n)]/
                 ProductLog[0.3678 Log[0.3989 (0.03653 + n)]]]},
  While[bound! > n, bound--]; bound];

k=10000!+1*^10
invfactorialbound[k] // Timing

(* {0.031200,10000} *)
```

That's on an old netbook. No idea how long `ArgMax` et. al. would take - they bomb out unevaluated, but on smaller k (~5000!) this was below timer resolution, `ArgMax` took 7 seconds...